# Nativescript App versioning discrepancy between Sidekick and xCode

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

I am setting up my NS 6.4.2 app in Sidekick as Application Version 5.00 and Application Build Version as 5.03.

[image]

When I run tns ios prepare --release on my Mac and open Xcode to publish the app, I see Verson 5.03 and Build 5.00.

[image]

It looks like the numbers are flipped.  Is this a bug or I am missing something?